# how to combine multiple css class selectors for jquery buttonset?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a JQuery buttonset and am setting the icon, when hovered over or when active, to a colored version of the icon so it stands out. The css looks like:

```
.ui-button .ui-icon.line {
    background-image: url("/static/16x16/line-black.gif");
}
.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-icon.line {
    background-image: url("/static/16x16/line-color.gif");
}
.ui-button.ui-state-active .ui-icon.line {
    background-image: url("/static/16x16/line-color.gif");
}
```

The above css works fine. My question is whether there is a way to combine the 2nd and 3rd css rules.

I have tried, among other variations, this:

```
.ui-button .ui-icon.line {
    background-image: url("/static/16x16/line-black.gif");
}
.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-button.ui-state-active .ui-icon.line {
    background-image: url("/static/16x16/line-color.gif");
}
```

But I haven't found a combination that works.

Is there a way to combine the two combinations (.ui-button.ui-state-hover and .ui-button.ui-state-active) in one css selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate multiple selectors with a comma:

```
.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-icon.line, .ui-button.ui-state-active .ui-icon.line {
    background-image: url("/static/16x16/line-color.gif");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is either approach considered a best practice?

Comment: I think the main point of the "don't repeat yourself" principle is to make code cleaner, but also to make changes easier and less tricky. In this case, if you're likely to change the background-image property and you're likely to want that to change for both selectors, then this is probably better. If not, I would almost find separating them to be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks - I find them easier to read when separated but wanted them to change together. I appreciate your perspective.